# PHP Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer: How can you set print quality to Draft?

Tags: php, excel, pear

I'm printing hundreds of pages everyday using web application written in PHP.
I want to set the print quality to "DRAFT" to save on printer ink and to save time.

For now, I manually set the print quality to "Draft" before printing in excel.

My question is: How to programmatically print it from `PHP-PEAR-SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_WRITER` ?

I was expecting I could set the print quality like this but there is no command for that.

`$worksheet->setPrintQuality('Draft');`

Is there any other way? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe printer quality is a printer-specific setting, like color mode or duplex printing. Since each printer is different, it's handled by the printer driver. As such, there may not be a general, easy way to set a printer to "draft" quality programatically. (For example, some printers can't even do this)

What you might do is look into what documentation you can find for the specific printer/printer driver you are working with. Maybe there is some sort of API or command line you can use somewhere to interact with the driver or set its default quality to 'draft.'